# laravel using whereBetween for count multiple table

Tags: laravel

> function fetch_c(Request $request)
> {
> if($request->ajax())
> {
> if($request->from_date != '' && $request->to_date != '')
> {
>
> ```
>      $data = DB::select("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pos) as a, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers) as b, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
> ```
>
> supplires) as c")
> ->whereBetween('created_at', array($request->from_date, $request->to_date));
> }
> else
> {
> $data = DB::select("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pos) as a, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers) as b, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
> supplires) as c");
> }
> echo json_encode($data);
> }
> }

Comment: This question doesn't have enough or any details. Please provide more details to it.

Comment: $data = DB::select("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pos) as a, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers) as b, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM supplires) as c")
         ->whereBetween('created_at', array($request->from_date, $request->to_date));

Comment: this query is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
 function fetch_c(Request $request)
    {
     if($request->ajax())
     {
      if($request->from_date != '' && $request->to_date != '')
      {
        
         $data = DB::select("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pos) as a, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers) as b, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM supplires) as c")
         ->whereBetween('created_at', array($request->from_date, $request->to_date));
        }
      else
      {
        $data = DB::select("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pos) as a, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers) as b, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM supplires) as c");
    }
      echo json_encode($data);
     }
    }
```

---

### ajax

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 var date = new Date();

 $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
  todayBtn: 'linked',
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  autoclose: true
 });
 var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

 fetch_data();

 function fetch_data(from_date = '', to_date = '')
 {

  $.ajax({
   url:"{{ url('fetch_c') }}",
   method:"get",
   data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(data)
   {
    console.log(data);
    // $("#max_score").val(data);
   }
  })

 $('#filter').click(function(){
  var from_date = $('#from_date').val();
  var to_date = $('#to_date').val();
  if(from_date != '' &&  to_date != '')
  {
   fetch_data(from_date, to_date);
  }
  else
  {
   alert('Both Date is required');
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

Route

```
Route::get('/fetch_c', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'fetch_c']);
```

Error

GET http://localhost:8000/fetch_c?from_date=2022-03-01&to_date=2022-03-31 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: HOW TO SLOVE THIS ERROR AND FETCH RECORD MANY TABELS ROW COUNT WITH USE CONDITION whereBetween